# How to use: for i in range(): except it doesn't run from 1 - 20 it runs from 5 - 20 or something?

Tags: python

For example:

```
for i in range(5 - 20):
    if playerx == i:
         # the player dies
```

I know that you can't put a tuple there but I mean how would I do 5 - 20 Thanks!

Comment: are you asking for  `range(5, 20)`?

Comment: You just subtracted 20 from 5. Is `range(5,20)` what you intended?

Comment: Read the doc fist if you see strange behavior. No programmer is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, use range(5, 20). The [range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) function accepts three parameters: the start, stop and step in the desired range. Hence, here we have a start at 5 and end at 20 (excluded).

```
>>> list(range(5, 20))
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: so would I just do for i in range(list)?